# Derivative of a column-normalized complex matrix

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus, several-complex-variables

> Note: I have found the answer to this and left my working below

I am trying to find the derivative
$\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast}$
which I have already reduced to
\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&= \dfrac{\operatorname{Tr}(({\partial J}/{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast})^T\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast)}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
+ \dfrac{\operatorname{Tr}(({\partial J}/{\partial \mathbf{B}})^T\partial\mathbf{B})}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}\\
&=\sum_{k,l}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kl}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{kl}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}} + \sum_{k,l}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kl}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}_{kl}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
\end{align}
using [this](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf). $J$ is a real-valued scalar that depends on $\mathbf{A}$. The matrices $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ are related by
$$\mathbf{B}_{ij} = \dfrac{\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}$$
i.e. $\mathbf{B}$ is an $L_2$ column-normalized $\mathbf{A}$

However, I can't quite figure out how to proceed with the differentiation. I would appreciate any help!

> My attempt:

We focus on
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{kl}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
\dfrac{\mathbf{A}_{kl}^\ast}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{ml}\mathbf{A}_{ml}^\ast}}
\end{align}
which is zero if $l\ne j$, so I now consider
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{kj}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
\dfrac{\mathbf{A}_{kj}^\ast}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}
\end{align}

For the case where $i=k$,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
\dfrac{\mathbf{A}_{ij}^\ast}{\sqrt{\mathbf{A}_{ij}\mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij} + \sum_{m\ne i}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\\
&=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}\right)\\
\end{align}
For the case where $i\ne k$,
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{ij}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
\dfrac{\mathbf{A}_{kj}^\ast}{\sqrt{\mathbf{A}_{ij}\mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij} + \sum_{m\ne i}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\\
&=
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\mathbf{A}^\ast_{kj}\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}\right)\\
\end{align}

So we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\operatorname{Tr}(({\partial J}/{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast})^T\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast)}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\sum_{k}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kj}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{kj}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{ij}-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\sum_{k}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kj}\dfrac{\mathbf{A}^\ast_{kj}\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}
\end{align}

We now ignore $l\ne j$ again and consider
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}_{kj}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
\dfrac{\mathbf{A}_{kj}^\ast}{\sqrt{\mathbf{A}_{ij}\mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij} + \sum_{m\ne i}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}
=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\mathbf{A}^\ast_{kj}\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}\right)\\
\end{align}

So we have
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\operatorname{Tr}(({\partial J}/{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast})^T\partial\mathbf{B})}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&=\sum_{k}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kj}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}_{kj}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}\\
&=-\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\sum_{k}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kj}\dfrac{\mathbf{A}^\ast_{kj}\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}
\end{align}

Thus the overall expression evaluates
\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
&= \dfrac{\operatorname{Tr}(({\partial J}/{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast})^T\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast)}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}
+ \dfrac{\operatorname{Tr}(({\partial J}/{\partial \mathbf{B}})^T\partial\mathbf{B})}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}\\
&=\sum_{k,l}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kl}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}^\ast_{kl}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}} + \sum_{k,l}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kl}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{B}_{kl}}{\partial \mathbf{A}^\ast_{ij}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{ij}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\sum_{k}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kj}\dfrac{\mathbf{A}^\ast_{kj}\mathbf{A}_{ij}}{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\sum_{m}\mathbf{A}_{mj}\mathbf{A}_{mj}^\ast}}\left[\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{ij}-\mathbf{B}_{ij}\sum_{k}\left(\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \mathbf{B}^\ast}\right)_{kj}\mathbf{B}^\ast_{kj}\right]
\end{align}

Comment: What is $J$ here?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Hi, $J$ is a real-valued scalar that depends on $\mathbf{A}$. Sorry I forgot to mention. I have edited that in.

Comment: And I don't understand your notation $(\nabla_{\mathbf{A}^\ast}J)_{ij}$. What are the indices $i,i$ here for? $\nabla_{\mathbf{A}^\ast}J$ is a scalar value.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net that's the derivative of $J$ with respect to $\mathbf{A}^\ast$, which is a matrix of the same size as $\mathbf{A}$.

Comment: This confuses me... You told that $J$ is a scalar value. And I don't see why $A^*$ is coming into play vs. $\nabla_{\mathbf{A}^\ast}J$???

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net $J$ is a real-valued scalar function of a matrix $\mathbf{A}$,by definition the gradient is a matrix too.

Comment: $\nabla_{\mathbf{A}^\ast}J$ is not the gradient. It is [the directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative).

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net pardon the notation. The paper I was referencing uses nabla as gradient and $\frak{D}$ for directional derivative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given two matrices $(X,Y)$ with the same shape (equal #rows and columns), denote their Hadamard and Frobenius products as
$\;\;X\odot Y,\;\;X:Y\!=\!{\rm Tr}(X^TY),\;$ respectively.

Let's also use $(X^T,X^C,X^*)$ to denote the transpose, complex and hermitian conjugates of $X$.

Recall that the elements of the [Gram matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix) $(A^*A)$ are the inner products of the columns of $A$. In particular, the $k^{th}$ diagonal element is equal to the square of the length of the $k^{th}$ column of $A$.

If we create a vector $(h)$ of the lengths of the columns of $A$, then it must satisfy 
$$\eqalign{
h\odot h &= {\rm diag}(A^*A) \\
2h\odot dh &= {\rm diag}(A^*dA+dA^*A) \\
}$$
It will proved convenient to use $h$ to create a diagonal matrix as well as its inverse.
$$\eqalign{
H &= {\rm Diag}(h),\quad Y=H^{-1} \\
2H\odot dH &= {\rm Diag}\Big({\rm diag}(A^*dA+dA^*A)\Big) \\
 dH &= \tfrac{1}{2}Y\odot\big(A^*dA+dA^*A\big) \\ 
}$$
Note that $(H,Y)$ matrices are symmetric and their elements are all *real*.

Using these new variables, we can write $B=AY$.

The stated goal is to find the gradient of a real scalar function $(J)$ with respect to $A$, given its gradient $(G)$ with respect to $B$. We will approach this problem by calculating the differential of $J$, and then performing a change of variables from $B\to A$.

The differential will consist of a set of terms plus their hermitian conjugates. To save horizontal space, I'll only write the first set of terms and simply make reference to the conjugate terms. 
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= G:dB + G^*:dB^* \\
   &= G:dB
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= G:d(AY)
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= GY:dA + A^TG:dY
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= GY:dA - A^TG:Y\,dH\,Y
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= GY:dA - YA^TGY:dH
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= GY:dA - \tfrac{1}{2}\big(YA^TGY\big):Y\odot\big(A^*dA+dA^*A\big)
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= GY:dA - \tfrac{1}{2}(Y^3\odot A^TG):\big(A^*dA+dA^*A\big)
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= \Big(GY-\tfrac{1}{2}A^{C}(Y^3\odot A^TG)\Big):dA - \tfrac{1}{2}(Y^3\odot A^TG)A^T:dA^*
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
}$$
At this point, we notice that a term involving $dA^*$ has appeared, which means that in the conjugate there is a corresponding term involving $dA$. Swap these and collect all of the terms involving $dA$.
$$\eqalign{
dJ
   &= \Big(GY-\tfrac{1}{2}A^{C}(Y^3\odot A^TG + (Y^3\odot A^TG)^*)\Big):dA 
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= \Big(GY-A^{C}\,{\cal Re}(Y^3\odot A^TG)\Big):dA 
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= \Big(GY-A^{C}R\Big):dA 
&\quad+\quad{conj} \\
   &= \big(GY-A^{C}R\big):dA \;+\; \big(GY-A^{C}R\big)^*:dA^* 
}$$
This gives us our expression for the new gradient
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial J}{\partial A}
 &= GY-A^{C}R \\ 
 &= \bigg(\frac{\partial J}{\partial B}\bigg)Y-A^{C}\,{\cal Re}\Bigg(Y^3\odot A^T\bigg(\frac{\partial J}{\partial B}\bigg)\Bigg) \\ 
}$$
and its conjugate (which is what this question actually asks for) 
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial J}{\partial A^*}
&= YG^*-RA^T \\ 
 &= Y\bigg(\frac{\partial J}{\partial B^*}\bigg)-{\cal Re}\Bigg(Y^3\odot \bigg(\frac{\partial J}{\partial B^*}\bigg)^CA\Bigg)\,A^T \\ 
}$$

Comment: Hi @greg thanks a lot for the answer. I notice that a few people here use $:$ for Frobenius norm. However I don’t see this notation in either the matrix cookbook or the complex matrix differentiation paper. So I suppose there is another common reference paper that people use for (complex) matrix differentiation. Do you mind sharing about it?

Comment: Can you help to explain how $\tfrac{1}{2}\big(YA^TGY\big):Y\odot\big(A^*dA+dA^*A\big)$ becomes $\tfrac{1}{2}(Y^3\odot A^TG):\big(A^*dA+dA^*A\big)$ please

Comment: Let
$$\eqalign{
 Y = {\rm Diag}(y),\quad
 M = A^TG,\quad
dX = (A^*dA+dA^*A) \\
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
YMY:Y\odot dX
 &= Y\odot (YMY):dX \\
 &= Y\odot (yy^T\odot M):dX \\
 &= (Y\odot yy^T)\odot M:dX \\
 &= Y^3\odot M:dX \\
}$$
The first step is due to the commutivity of the Hadamard and Frobenius products. The second step uses the diagonal nature of $Y$. Subsequent steps group terms using associativity.

Comment: I see. Thank you